# ROC curve going below diagonal

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc

I made an ROC curve for three classifiers and am getting the following results:

[image]

My blue and orange lines are going under the diagonal and I'm pretty sure that's not supposed to happen. Does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: Yes, it's a bad model.

Comment: Yes the response changes. First you predict the opposite then you are ok so you probably have a non linear response. The Forest missclassifies at the beginning, wrong buckets size I guess. Green just gets away with it, but you have mix responses at the beginning for lower value. Your data is probably mixed up there with 0 and 1 difficult to separate and then beyond a threshold it becomes easier. Then depends on sample size...